# GPIO Raspberry Pi Python

Tags: python, gpio

I can't figure out where my problem is. Would be nice if anyone is able to help me. Mqtt works good, but everytime the GPIO gets triggered the program crashes.

Error:

> Connected with result code 0
>
> /test/light1 0 0 Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "garage.py", line 33, in 
>       client.loop_forever()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line
>   1481, in loop_forever
>       rc = self.loop(timeout, max_packets)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line
>   1003, in loop
>       rc = self.loop_read(max_packets)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line
>   1284, in loop_read
>       rc = self._packet_read()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line
>   1849, in _packet_read
>       rc = self._packet_handle()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line
>   2305, in _packet_handle
>       return self._handle_publish()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line
>   2500, in _handle_publish
>       self._handle_on_message(message)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line
>   2647, in _handle_on_message
>       self.on_message(self, self._userdata, message)   File "garage.py", line 22, in on_message
>       GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.LOW) RuntimeError: The GPIO channel has not been set up as an OUTPUT

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

pin = 15

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.HIGH)

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code " + str(rc))

    client.subscribe("/test/light1")

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
        print(msg.topic + " " + str(msg.payload))
        if msg.payload == "0":
                print("0")
                GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.LOW)
        if msg.payload == "1":
                print("1")
                GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.HIGH)

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

client.connect("192.168.178.60", 1883, 60)

client.loop_forever()
```

Comment: The error is clear you have not setup the GPIO channel as an output `GPIO.setup(channel, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.HIGH)` `chan_list = [11,12]                             # also works with tuples
GPIO.output(chan_list, GPIO.LOW)                # sets all to GPIO.LOW
GPIO.output(chan_list, (GPIO.HIGH, GPIO.LOW))   # sets first HIGH and second LOW`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.HIGH)` to set the initial value (after setting mode output) when you should be calling `GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.HIGH)`. Alternatively you could use `GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.HIGH)`.

Answer (score 0):

On fist glance, I would think the issue would be the GPIO.setup is not propagated to the defined functions. Rather than define them globally at the top, make a sub method

```
def gpio_setup():
  pin = 15

  GPIO.setwarnings(False)
  GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

  GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)
  GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.HIGH)
```

And then call that method in each of the other methods:

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
  gpio_setup()
```

You could even start just by setting the GPIO.setup manually in each method to find where it breaks.